# Redirect to a subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following system folders:

```
.htaccess

- www
  - index.html
  - assets
  - dev
  - prod
```

When you access to the domain's url `(www.example.com)`, you see the `index.html`.

Well, I just want to redirect to the subfolder `prod` every ip's but mine. I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^ myIP
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/prod/ [L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code has syntax error.  Better you show your full .htaccess in question and state clearly what's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^prod/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

please refer this:
http://beginnersbook.com/2013/08/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-using-htaccess/

Comment: please refer the link